# How to create an appointment using C# VSTO and display the Schedule Assistant view

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to add C# code (in my Outlook VSTO Addin) to create an appointment and show the Schedule Assistant view when it's displayed.

Below is the code I've written so far which creates an appointment, adds the recipient. But when the Display method is called, its displayed showing the default Appointment view. I want it to display the Schedule Assistant view and show the recipients I just added.

```
AppointmentItem newAppointment = Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

Recipients sentTo = newAppointment.Recipients;
Recipient sentInvite = null;
sentInvite = sentTo.Add(emailAddress);
sentInvite.Type = (int)OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
sentTo.ResolveAll();
newAppointment.Display();
```

**UPDATE**

In my VSTO add-in project I've added a UserControl. And in this UserControl I have a Button control. And when the Button is clicked it runs the following code:

```
AppointmentItem newAppointment = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
newAppointment.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;

Inspector inspector = newAppointment.GetInspector;
CommandBarControl commandBarControl = inspector.CommandBars.FindControl(Type.Missing, 14935);
commandBarControl.Execute();

Recipients recipients = newAppointment.Recipients;
Recipient readyByRecipient = null;
readyByRecipient = recipients.Add(emailAddress);
readyByRecipient.Type = (int)OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
recipients.ResolveAll();
newAppointment.Display();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(readyByRecipient);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newAppointment);
```

Unfortunatey when I call the FindControl method (passing the ID value from the OutlookAppointmentItemControls.xlsx file) it returns null, so I can't call `commandBarControl.Execute()` to show the Schedule Assistant view.

And I've also tried calling the FindControl method after calling `newAppointment.Display()`, but it still returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The solution is to call the [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx) method with the Control Name value from the OutlookAppointmentItemControls.xlsx file. And it only seems to work if you call the ExecuteMso after the Display method has been called.

Below is the code to create a new Appointment (meeting) with a recipient, and show the Schedule Assistant view in the Inspector window.

```
AppointmentItem newAppointment = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
newAppointment.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;

Recipients recipients = newAppointment.Recipients;
Recipient readyByRecipient = null;
readyByRecipient = recipients.Add(emailAddress);
readyByRecipient.Type = (int)OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
recipients.ResolveAll();
newAppointment.Display();

Inspector inspector = newAppointment.GetInspector;
inspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("ShowSchedulingPage");

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(readyByRecipient);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newAppointment);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inspector);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [MeetingStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869205(v=office.15).aspx) property of the AppointmentItem class to the *olMeeting* value before calling the Display method. For example:

```
Sub CreateAppt()
  Dim myItem As Object 
  Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)  
  myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
  myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting"
  myItem.Location = "Conference Room B" 
  myItem.Start = #9/24/2015 1:30:00 PM# 
  myItem.Duration = 90  
  Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Nate Sun")  
  myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired  
  Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Kevin Kennedy")  
  myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional  
  Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Conference Room B")  
  myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource  
  myItem.Display  
End Sub
```

To see the Schedule Assistant view you can run the corresponding button on the ribbon programmatically. The Execute method of the CommandBars class can be used to run the Scheduling button. You just need to pass idMso of the built-in control. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) for actual values.

Comment: It now shows that the invited person as a To recipient, and the Send button is now visible (which is good). But the appointment is still displayed in the standard Appointment view (and not in the Schedule Assistant view) when the Display method is called.

Comment: You can use the Execute method of the CommandBars class to run the Scheduling button on the ribbon programmatically. You just need to pass idMso of the built-in control. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) for actual values.

Comment: I've downloaded the zip file from the Microsoft site and opened the OutlookAppointmentItemControls.xlsx file. And found the ShowSchedulingPage control row, but none of the numbers on the row execute the button (or even return the button) when I pass it into the Execute method. Any ideas how I can get the correct ID value?

Comment: I've added the details of where I'm running the code, and the code I'm running in the UPDATE section of my first question.

Comment: There is no need to use the FindControl method. You can find the actual values in [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798). Use the commandBars.Execute("ShowSchedulingPage") instead.